# Inf in Excel using Matlab xlswrite()

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to write Inf and -Inf using xlswrite in Matlab.
But value I'm getting in the xls is 65535 for both. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with the types of the value you want to store in a cell in Excel. First, Excel does not have any `inf` value (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145404/is-there-infinity-in-spreadsheets)). If you wish to store *a large number*, you can use e.g.

```
xlswrite('test.xls', 1e99, 1, 'A1')
```

however, at some point, Excel does simply go back to `65535`, if you use e.g.

```
xlswrite('test.xls', 1e9999, 1, 'A1') % gives you 65535 in Excel
```

A quick check yielded (MATLAB R2013b), that the largest number is `1e308`, so

```
xlswrite('test.xls', 1e308, 1, 'A1')
```