# Write Inf (numeric) into excel and read it back into R. Inf is char, rather than numeric

Tags: r, types, readxl, data-handling, writexl

After writing `Inf` (as `numeric`) into `excel`, I read it back again and get `Inf` as Char. For `NaN`, it becomes `NA`. For `NA`, it remains `NA` as `numeric`, which is supposed to be.

I used both `readxl` and `writexl`. I tried to install `tibble` and failed.

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

x <- c(1,NA)
y <- c(2,NaN)
z <- c(3,Inf)

d0 <- data.frame(x,y,z)

write_xlsx(d0, 'Test.xlsx')
d1 <- read_xlsx('Test.xlsx')

str(d0$x)
str(d0$y)
str(d0$z)

str(d1$x)
str(d1$y)
str(d1$z)
```

Here are results: Notice `NaN` becomes `NA`; `Inf` (`numeric`) becomes `Inf` (`character`)

```
> str(d0$x)
 num [1:2] 1 NA
> str(d0$y)
 num [1:2] 2 NaN
> str(d0$z)
 num [1:2] 3 Inf

> str(d1$x)
 num [1:2] 1 NA
> str(d1$y)
 num [1:2] 2 NA
> str(d1$z)
 chr [1:2] "3" "Inf"
```

I am looking for explanations and remedies during write and read phases. I am not looking for solutions after reading in such as setting `as.numeric(d1$z)`. I am verifying dataset output by third party using the same `R` code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks @joran for a quick response. If you open the saved excel file, you will see blank cells for NA and NaN; plus string "Inf" for Inf. When you read them back, NA and NaN become NA. "Inf" become Chr (the entire column becomes chr). Excel carries 4 special values: empty cell, null, #N/A, #DIV/0!. I wonder why write_xlsx does not carry an option for writing Inf as true infinite (here #DIV/0!). When you read it back, you will get Inf as numeric. Of course, Excel does not distinguish +Inf and -Inf.  Another complication: for 0/0, it is NaN in R and becomes #DIV/0! in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145404/is-there-infinity-in-spreadsheets) SO question about infinity in excel for some more info. Infinity is not available in excel. Before writing to excel you could set the `Inf` values to `.Machine$double.xmax`. This will be represented as `#NULL!` in excel. But reading `#NULL!` in again will automatically be represented as `Inf` in R. Strangely enough `-Inf` is represented in excel as the same value `#NULL!`.

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

d0 <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA),
                 y = c(2, NaN),
                 z = c(3, Inf),
                 z1 = c(4, -Inf))

d0[d0 == Inf] <- .Machine$double.xmax 
d0[d0 == -Inf] <- .Machine$double.xmax * -1


write_xlsx(d0, 'Test.xlsx')
d1 <- read_xlsx('Test.xlsx')
d1

# A tibble: 2 x 4
      x     y     z    z1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     4
2    NA    NA   Inf  -Inf
```

If you need to see the numbers in excel you would have to replace the `Inf` values with `9.99999E+307` and replace this number back to Inf when after you read the data back into R.