# How to maintain high decimal precision in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, fortran, fortran77

I am converting a FORTRAN code that maintains at least 16 decimal precision.
I am facing a problem of dividing by zero in VBA excel, but If I try the code below on [this online compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-fortran-online), I do not get a zero. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the fortran Code

```
program sum
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
x = 3.14159265358979
y = 1.24325643454325

z = (x*y)/dtan(0.0D0) 
print *, datan(.04D0*z)
end program sum
```

This is the VBA Code

```
Public Function dosomething()
Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Z As Double
X = 3.14159265358979
Y = 1.24325643454325
Z = (X * Y) / Tan(0#)
End Function
```

Comment: This doesn't look like VBA code. Mind sharing the actual VBA code if you want VBA people to help?

Comment: This is Fortran code, If I try it on the Fortran online compiler it works, but If I try that in VBA it doesn't work.

Comment: I should also add that dtan and datan are intrinsic functions in the Fortran library which equivalent to Tan() and Atn() in VBA.

Comment: I am not asking to translate the code, I am asking how to maintain high precision with numbers the same Fortran does so I do not end up dividing by zero....

Comment: I edited the code to include the VBA Code. Matt P, you can ignore that print statement, it is irrelevant and I removed it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I edited the code

Comment: The tangent of `0` is `0` so you are dividing by `0`, hence the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner the it should not be zero tho, it should be tan(1E-16)

Comment: But your code shows `Tan(0)` not `Tan(1E-16)`.  So put that in and you stop getting the `divided by 0` error.

Comment: With `Z = (X * Y) / Tan(1E-16)` I get Z= `3.90580528128931E+16 `

Comment: Note that to keep double precision in your `x` and `y` variables you must append the designator `d0` to the number, as in `x=3.14159265358979d0`. This is a common mistake. If you do not, the compiler usually assumes the variable is single precision and only the first 7 digits are retained from your original assignment.

Comment: As @MattP , says, with `print *, x` and `print *, y`, the output is `3.1415927410125732` and `1.2432564496994019` respectively, whereas if `d0` is appended to the assignments, the output is `3.1415926535897900` and `1.2432564345432500` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into too many details, Fortran can support real values (floats) of +/-Infinity and NaN, depending on how the value is calculated. For example, your original post contained two uninitialized variables which you then used to calculate `(v1 * v2)/dtan(0.0d0)`. Since uninitialized vars are often (but not always) set to 0, this calculation becomes `0.0/0.0`, which is mathematically undefined and the result is `NaN`.<sup>**1**</sup>

Now, if the numerator is positive, `z=(x*y)/dtan(0.0D0)` results in `z=Infinity`, regardless of what `x` and `y` are. If your system cannnot represent Infinity, then it uses "a very large number". That is evidently the case with VBA.

Finally, you calculate `datan(.04D0*z)`. Mathematically, this is *arctangent(Infinity)=PI/2*. And again, the correctly computed Fortran results match this, returning a double-precision value of `1.57079632679490`.<sup>**2**</sup>

Now, I don't know much about VBA, but it does not seem to support +/-Infinity or NaN. If a "very large number" results in significant error compared to what you are expecting in your final result, then it appears there are workarounds as described at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885994/how-do-you-get-vb6-to-initialize-doubles-with-infinity-infinity-and-nan).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Note that in Fortran with double precision you should get `dtan(0.0d0) = 0.000000000000000E+000`.

<sup>**2**</sup>
In order to maintain double-precision in the Fortran `x` and `y` variables, you **must** append `d0`. Otherwise they will become single-precision values by default and store only the first 7 sig figs from your original assignment, and it's up to the compiler what the remaining digits in the double-precision value take (usually just garbage).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Z = (X * Y) / Tan(0#)
> ```

The type hint on the `0` literal is superfluous, `Tan` function takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`. But `Tan(0)` returns `0`, so you *are* dividing by `0`.

Seems your online Fortran compiler is doing something funky.

> *it should not be zero tho, it should be tan(1E-16)*

No. That's mathematically wrong, VBA is doing it right. If you need your VBA code to be just as broken as that Fortran, then you need to handle the situation explicitly:

```
Z = (X * Y) / Tan(1E-16)
```

But just know that is mathematically wrong. I've not idea how the Fortran code manages to output `1.5707963267948966`. This VBA code outputs `3.90580528128931E+16`.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of it mathematically impossible, but I lurked your profile and it seems like you're comfortable with VBA. The code in fortran sets the variable to equal to 0.0D0, when I type that in VBA it changes it to 0#, not sure what that means. I assumed that 0# is equivalent to 0.0D0 in fortran and that's where the error is.

Comment: `0#` is a [type-hinted `Double` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201708111610376144341) with a value of `0`. BASIC originates in FORTRAN (from well before it got "Visual"), that's where the auto-correcting of the `D` came from. I've no idea how `0.0D0` could be anything other than `0` in FORTRAN though.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the Fortran code shown by the OP, but the correct mathematical result really is PI/2 or approx 1.57079632679490 in double precision. This is because `datan(.04D0*z)` is equivalent to arctangent(Infinity).

Comment: Evidently, your vba code doesn't match your arbitrary looking mixture of Fortran single and double precision.  You show x and y initialized single precision.

Comment: @tim18, If i append the variables with D0 it still doesn't change the outcome. I am confused at the part where z = (x*y)/dtan(0.0D0) equals infinity and not zero.